# Does someone lose muscle if they don't exercise?

Tags: muscle

I had great muscle gains about 6 months ago. But recently I have stopped exercising intensely so I have become slightly fat. Will I lose muscle if I do not lift weights?

Comment: Someone who works out intensely for 6 months should know the answer...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how well you eat and what you do with your life/body once you stop training, how far you got while you were training, your genetics, etc.

Muscle memory will most likely bring it back quicker than those who never lifted

Answer (score 0):

It has been proven that gains will still stay with you even years after, so not really. But gaining fat isn't a whole lot better then losing muscle.

Comment: "It has been proven" should be succeeded by a link to a study or another source.

Comment: Agree with @Alec, and it's not proven whether the gains are in the actual muscle or the amount of enervation/activation of the muscle.